# Swift 4: Parsing Firebase 4 snapshot to Model

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Swift 4 and Firebase 4

I have a Model called Part

```
class Part {
    var db_id: String?
    var can_8130: Bool?
    var description: String?
    var has_amm: Bool?
    var is_esd: Bool?
    var is_hazmat: Bool?
    var is_priority: Bool?
    var msn: String?
    var partNum: String?
    var received: String?
    var receiver: String?
    var tail: String?

    init(db_id:String?, can_8130: Bool, description: String?, has_amm: Bool?, is_esd: Bool?, is_hazmat: Bool?, is_priority: Bool?, msn: String?, partNum: String?, received: String?, receiver: String?, tail: String?) {
        self.db_id = db_id;
        self.can_8130 = can_8130;
        self.description = description;
        self.has_amm = has_amm;
        self.is_esd = is_esd;
        self.is_hazmat = is_hazmat;
        self.is_priority = is_priority;
        self.msn = msn;
        self.partNum = partNum;
        self.received = received;
        self.receiver = receiver;
        self.tail = tail;
    }
}
```

In my ViewController that serves as the UITableViewDataSource I have

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var partsArray: [Part] = []
```

In ViewDidLoad, I call retrieveParts() (from a Firebase4 Realtime Database)

```
function retrieveParts() {
    let rampPartsDB = Database.database().reference().child("ramp-parts")
    rampPartsDB.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
            //print(snapshot)
            if let snapValue = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
                print(snapValue)
                let dbID = snapValue["db_id"] as! String
                let can8130 = snapValue["can_8130"] as! Bool
                let description = snapValue["description"] as! String
                let hasAMM = snapValue["has_amm"] as! Bool
                let isESD = snapValue["is_esd"] as! Bool
                let isHazmat = snapValue["is_hazmat"] as! Bool
                let isPriority = snapValue["is_priority"] as! Bool
                let msn = snapValue["msn"] as! String
                let partNum = snapValue["partNum"] as! String
                let received = snapValue["received"] as! String
                let receiver = snapValue["receiver"] as! String
                let tail = snapValue["tail"] as! String

                var item = Part(db_id: dbID, can_8130: can8130, description: description, has_amm: hasAMM, is_esd: isESD, is_hazmat: isHazmat, is_priority: isPriority, msn: msn, partNum: partNum, received: received, receiver: receiver, tail: tail)
                print("ITEM: \(item)" )
                self.partsArray.append(item)
            }
        } // end if
    } // end observe()
} // end retrievePart()
```

Now, "Printing Parts Array" displays []

and

the statements print(snapValue) and print("ITEM: (item)" ) produce for each member:

> ["tail": N117UA, "is_priority": 0, "received": 2018-02-22T09:12:07S,
>   "can_8130": 1, "description": PARTS ON A PLANE, "is_hazmat": 0,
>   "is_esd": 1, "has_amm": 0, "partNum": b51-09-1035, "msn": ,
>   "receiver": Jon Gravois, "db_id": 99990] ITEM: Aero_Eco.Part

ANY help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show your reference tree as a picture.

Comment: added to question

Comment: How come your tree doesn't show 'ramp-parts'?

Comment: I think you are observing for childAdded instead of value.

Comment: That is the shot of the console in xcode so ramp-parts doesn't show

Comment: @jgravois What you want to do is just fill data from snapshot to model class ?

Comment: Should I be using value instead of childAdded? I am trying to learn this

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya yes (but after two days, "just" is an understatement)

Comment: @jgravois Your snapshot value is dictionary inside just put this code `if let snapValue  = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]' and inside that print `snapValue` you can see all key-value over there. From it get each value by key and create model and append to your arrray

Comment: I can print snapValue and that works!!! YAY!!!!

Comment: what about .childAdded versus .value?

Comment: @jgravois see answer

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I updated the question according to your suggestion ... thanks to you I think I am MUCH closer but it still isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your snapshot value is dictionary inside just put this code `if let snapValue = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]' and inside that`print `snapValue you can see all`key-value`over there. From it get each value by key and create model and append to your`partsArray`

There are several things you need to understand before diving in to firebase.

Firebase is a based on JSON (key - Value) realtime   Database type which allows to observer on any of key with several observers.

in which you can have following event types

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, FIRDataEventType) {
    /// A new child node is added to a location.
    FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded,
    /// A child node is removed from a location.
    FIRDataEventTypeChildRemoved,
    /// A child node at a location changes.
    FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged,
    /// A child node moves relative to the other child nodes at a location.
    FIRDataEventTypeChildMoved,
    /// Any data changes at a location or, recursively, at any child node.
    FIRDataEventTypeValue
} NS_SWIFT_NAME(DataEventType);
```

But There one more important thing is `observeSingleEventOfType` and `observeEventType` My suggestion is you to just go through to docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start

If you observe singleEvent it will execute only once when this statement executes. 
if you observe normal event it will be notify you whenever you get change in any of your subtree. so it is recommended to use it wisely and don't put observer on top of the tree object.

### What you should do if you need it only once.

Observe a single event on your key and then add another observer which is `childAdded`